# Add data to pandas dataframe using for loop with same key to all data dataframe already contains some data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tweepy

I have stored streaming data of twitter using tweepy.I have extracted name, lang, country, and text from data and stored in one pandas dataframe.
Now I wanted to add gender field to same dataframe which is i am getting from gender api by GEt request by using for loop.
How can i add that gender column to same dataframe?

tweets_data contains all data, I am using nameparser to find first name

```
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweets_data)
tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data)
tweets['name'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['name'], tweets_data)
tweets1=pd.DataFrame()
tweets1['name1'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['name'], tweets_data)
gender_data=[]
for i,v in tweets.iterrows(): 
    try:
        name1 = v['name']
        name = HumanName(name1)
        PARAMS = {'name':name['first']} 
        r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS) 
        data = r.json() 
        name = data['name'] 
        gender = data['gender'] 
        gender_data.append(gender)
        print(gender_data)
    except:
        continue
tweets1=pd.DataFrame(gender_data,columns=['gender'])
tweets.merge(tweets1,how='left', left_on='name', right_on='name1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas allows your to just add the field.
Take the following frame:

`my_frame = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['bob', 'jack']})`

[image]

You can add the gender column like this:

```
my_frame['gender'] = [1,2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have learnt python just 15 days back and now implementing this as an academic project.

Comment: If it answered you, please mark this one as the answer. Good luck in your projects!